# Transparently piping a function's parameters through another function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, casting

I'm building a fairly large JavaScript library made of hundreds of functions. Each function has a certain number of parameters, sometime not known at design time. I need to pipe every function parameter through some kind of parameter `cleanUp()` function. I could do something like that:

```
function myFunction(param1, param2, ..., paramN) {
  var param1 = cleanUp(param1);
  var param2 = cleanUp(param2);
  ...
  var paramN = cleanUp(paramN);

  // Function's implementation goes here
}

function cleanUp(param) {
  // Cleanup code goes here
  return cleanParam;
}
```

But that would be quite verbose and repetitive (remember, I have hundreds of these functions).

**My question is:** what would be the best way to transparently pipe all the function's parameters through the `cleanUp` function, either with inheritance, or anything more appropriate. I know that I can use the `arguments` variable to access all the functions' parameters, but I would like the cleanup to happen *outside* of the functions themselves, into some other function that my functions could "inherit" from.

**Note:** within all the functions, parameters must keep their original names for readability purposes.

Comment: Loop through the `arguments` variable that contains all of the parameters for a function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I clarified my question accordingly.

Comment: javascript doesn't (directly) support inheritance

Comment: @DoXicK I understand, and that's precisely why I was looking for some pattern that could achieve something similar. It might not exist, but I suspect that prototype could help. I just need to wrap my mind around it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could phrase it "How to create a proxy to transparently evaluate a function's parameters?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I didn't word my question properly, but I'm still not sure how to improve it.

Anyway, here is an answer I got from a colleague at work. In a Jeopardy kind of way, I'd love if someone could reword my initial question in order to match the answer I was looking for, because I'm pretty sure the resulting Q&A has some value.

```
// Parameter cleanup function
function cleanUp(param) {
  // Cleanup code goes here
  return cleanParam;
}

// Implementation of one of the hundreds of functions in the library
function _myFunction(param1, param2, ..., paramN) {
  // Function's implementation goes here
}

// Proxy of one of these functions with clean parameters
function myFunction = makeProxy(_myFunction);

// Utility function to create a proxies for the library functions
function makeProxy(fn) {
  function proxy() {
    var cleanParams = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      cleanParams.push(cleanUp(arguments[i]));
    }
    return fn.apply(this, cleanParams);
  }
  return proxy;
}
```

Thank you Pascal!

Comment: never thought about using the proxy pattern for this. learning something new every day :-) as a suggestion for the title you could use these keywords: proxy, encapsulation, pre-process/evalute, parameter mapping. You could even think about adding a second parameter for the makeProxy function so you can pass the cleanUp function with it. makeProxy(_myFunction, cleanUp);

Comment: it took me some time and additional offline discussion to understand what Ismael was trying to accomplish.  Not sure how to word the answer in a way that doesn't make the answer "obvious"

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'arguments' variable in the function. It's a list of... well... all the arguments :-)

```
function test (a,b) {
   console.log(arguments);
}
test('test','test');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I clarified my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

//Pass the internal arguments object

```
function myFunction(param1, param2, ..., paramN) {
  var paramters = cleanUp(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I clarified my question accordingly.